# Are the Error Bounds for Upper and Lower Riemann Sum the same as Left and Right Riemann Sum?

Tags: numerical-methods, riemann-sum

For the left and right Riemann sum, an error bound is given by:

|Error| $\leq \frac{(B-A)^2}{2N} M_1$ where $M_1 = \max_{x \in [A,B]}f'(x)$.

I can't seem to find any information on the error bounds for the upper and lower Riemann sums however. Are they the same or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $t_k$ be the evaluation point on the interval $[x_k,x_{k+1}]$ where $x_{k+1}-x_k=h$, $Nh=B-A$.
Then on that interval
$$
|f(x)-f(t_k)|\le M_1·|x-t_k|
$$

In the integral over that interval this gives
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}f(x)dx-f(t_k)(x_{k+1}-x_k)\right|
&\le\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}|f(x)-f(t_k)|dx
\\&\le M_1·\int_{x_k}^{x_{k+1}}|x-t_k|dx
\\&=M_1·\frac{(x_{k+1}-t_k)^2+(x_k-t_k)^2}2\le M_1·\frac{(x_{k+1}-x_k)^2}2
\end{align}
This shows that the claimed bound is valid for Riemann sums of all kinds.